# show that $ \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{\binom{x}{k}\binom{N-x}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}} = \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{x-k}}{\binom{N}{x}} $

Tags: combinatorics

I found this formula in a book

$$  \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{\binom{x}{k}\binom{N-x}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}
= \sum_{k = 0}^N \frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{x-k}}{\binom{N}{x}} $$

Notice $n \leftrightarrow x$.

Is there a proof using combinatorics?  What are both sides counting?  I know that $\binom{N}{k}$ counts the way of partitioning $N$ objects into groups of $k$ and $N-k$.

I am really looking for a **bijctive** proof if possible

Comment: Isn't both side just $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can rearrange the identity and give a combinatorial proof, as **i707107** did, but it’s really not much more than a disguised form of [Vandermonde’s identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity), which has a very easy combinatorial proof that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity#Combinatorial_proof) (and in the answers to a number of questions on this site). By Vandermonde’s identity

$$\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{x}k\binom{N-x}{n-k}=\binom{N}n$$

and

$$\sum_{k=0}^N\binom{n}k\binom{N-n}{x-k}=\binom{N}x\;,$$

so both sides are $1$.

Answer (score 5):

Both sides equate to $1$.

This comes from Hypergeometric Distribution.  For the LHS, the situation is that you have $N$ colored balls consisting of $x$ red balls and $N-x$ blue balls. 
Let $X$ be the number of red balls in a random selection of $n$ balls. Then we have
$$
P(X=k)=\frac{\binom xk \binom {N-x}{n-k}}{\binom Nn}.
$$
Summing this for $0\leq k \leq N$ (note that binomial coefficient $\binom ab$ is zero when $a<b$. ), we have
$$
1=\sum_{k=0}^N P(X=k) = \sum_{k=0}^N\frac{\binom xk \binom {N-x}{n-k}}{\binom Nn}.
$$

The RHS is treated similarly, and equates to $1$. Hence, both sides are $1$.

For the equality without the summation (which I think you meant in the first place, and @Dolma gave an algebraic proof), we prove that 
$$
\binom Nx\binom xk\binom{N-x}{n-k} = \binom Nn\binom nk\binom{N-n}{x-k}.
$$
The LHS is the number of ways to partition $\{1,\cdots ,N\}$ as a disjoint union $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ where 
$$
|A|=k, \ |B|=x-k, \ |C|=n-k, \ |D|=N-x-n+k.
$$
On the other hand, the RHS is the number of ways to partition $\{1,\cdots ,N\}$ as a disjoint union $A\cup B\cup C\cup D$ as 
$$
|A|=k, \ |B|=n-k, \ |C|=x-k, \ |D|=N-x-n+k.
$$
Therefore, both sides are equal.

Comment: Much more elegant than my proof indeed :) At first the two expressions reminded me a lot of Vandermonde's identity (when taking the denominators out of the sums), but then just went for the algebraic proof

Comment: @Dolma Thank you. I think both ways have their advantages. I wouldn't be able to come up with this proof without knowing algebraically that they have to be equal (for the second part).

Comment: If the roles of "selected" and "red" are switched then $P(X=k)$ will take the form of the term on RHS. So as @Dolma proved: $F=G$.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is quite immediate actually, all you need to do to prove it is simply to expand all the terms on each side of the equation.

If you restate your problem as:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}F=\sum_{k=0}^{N}G
$$

Now just evaluate *F* and *G*:

$$
F=\frac{{x \choose k}{N-x \choose n-k}}{{N \choose n}}=\frac{\frac{x!}{k!\cdot (x-k)!}\cdot\frac{(N-x)!}{(n-k)!\cdot ((N-x)-(n-k))!}}{\frac{N!}{n!\cdot (N-n)!}}
$$

$$
\Rightarrow F=\frac{x!\cdot (N-x)!\cdot n!\cdot (N-n)!}{N!\cdot k!\cdot (x-k)!\cdot (n-k)!\cdot((N-x)-(n-k))!}
$$

Same thing for *G* gets you:

$$
G=\frac{{n \choose k}{N-n \choose x-k}}{{N \choose x}}=\frac{\frac{n!}{k!\cdot (n-k)!}\cdot\frac{(N-n)!}{(x-k)!\cdot ((N-n)-(x-k))!}}{\frac{N!}{x!\cdot (N-x)!}}
$$

$$
\Rightarrow G=\frac{n!\cdot (N-n)!\cdot x!\cdot (N-x)!}{N!\cdot k!\cdot (n-k)!\cdot (x-k)!\cdot((N-n)-(x-k))!}
$$

Now, let *L* be:

$$
L=\frac{x!\cdot (N-x)!\cdot n!\cdot (N-n)!}{N!\cdot k!\cdot (x-k)!\cdot (n-k)!}
$$

You can rewrite both terms *F* and *G* as:

$$
F=\frac{L}{((N-x)-(n-k))!}
$$

and

$$
G=\frac{L}{((N-n)-(x-k))!}
$$

Moreover:

$$
((N-n)-(x-k))! = (N-n-x+k)! = (N-x-n+k)! = ((N-x)-(n-k))!
$$

Thus, *F=G* and:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{N}F=\sum_{k=0}^{N}G
$$

Comment: Just my opinion: If you would leave out the whole part that starts with "Now, let $L$ be:..." then your proof would gain elegance without loosing validity.

Answer (score 0):

Let a set with $N$ elements be split up randomly twice. This in:

two sets $A$ and $B$ that contain $n$ and $N-n$ elements respectively, and

two sets $U$ and $V$ that contain $x$ and $N-x$ respectively.

$|A\cap U|=k\wedge |A\cap V|=n-k\iff|A\cap U|=k\wedge |B\cap U|=x-k$

So these events have equal probabilities:
$$\frac{\binom{x}{k}\binom{N-x}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}=\frac{\binom{n}{k}\binom{N-n}{x-k}}{\binom{N}{x}}$$